# How to add custom field on Enterprise reports

Tags: enterprise, odoo-15

I'm using odoo15 an I create custom field in account.move and i want to make this field display in the table of the

Aged receivable and Aged payable in accounting=> reports

how can i do this?!

I want the display the field after account field in the table of the Aged receivable and Aged payable